# How can I show an gzipped http response to an image in flutter

Tags: flutter, gzip

I've been trying to show an image from Amazon S3 to my flutter application, but I am using Amazon CloudFront to cache my file. Now what happens is, when I get the http response,

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            'https://xyzbucketname.s3.xyzregion.amazonaws.com/filename.gz'
            ),
        headers: <String, String>{'accept-encoding': 'gzip'},
      );
```

when I try to show the image from these bytes like this

```
Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(response.bodyBytes)))
```

I get an error ***Exception:Invalid Image Data*** in my flutter app.

How do I show image in my flutter app by reading bytes from the response?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if the server response's header is `Content-Encoding: gzip` you need to use `GZipDecoder` to decode compressed data

Comment: Yes, the Content-Type header is application/x-gzip but I used GZipDecoder it did not help.

Comment: what are the first 8-16 bytes of decompressed data then?

Comment: These are the first 16 bytes when I do GzipDecoder()- [35, 86, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 58, 32, 49, 46, 48, 10, 35, 70,

Comment: When I simply print the response bytes these are the bytes- [31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 157, 84, 77, 111, 155, 64,

Comment: your uncompressed data is in ascii: `#Version: 1.0`, are you sure your server sends the right file? it is not any image format that flutter accepts